# preview, problem with showing floats

Tags: preview

In preparing an answer for SE, I suddenly stuck with preview package. LaTeXing the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
% dummy text ...
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c*{6}{S[table-number-alignment = center,
                                   table-figures-integer = 7]}
                }
\toprule
 0  & {1} &  {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} \\
\midrule
 1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I receive error: `Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles`. If I force pdfLaTeX to continue with compilation, it finish with it and gives the following preview:

[image]

If I recall correctly, some times ago similar cases work. Meanwhile I only update my MikTeX installation, but between packages I didn't saw `preview` package. Do have my MWE some error or is there something else in question?

Comment: The problem is that no page is output and the float, by default, has options `tbp`, so it remains pending waiting for something that triggers flushing the queue, which doesn't arrive. When the output routine has been called `\maxdeadcycles` times, TeX changes the output routine to the default one (just ship out box 255), so the float finally finds its way on a page. The `[h]` option to `table` allows placing the float “here“, so it can be output.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for your explanation! Please, make it as an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it will interest someone ... The problem with `floats` option disappear, if to float environment is added position option `h`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]% with added position option h works as desired
\begin{tabular}{c*{6}{S[table-number-alignment = center,
                                   table-figures-integer = 7]}
                }
\toprule
 0  & {1} &  {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} \\
\midrule
 1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Why this help, I still not understand. Because other options `t`, `b` doesn't work.

Comment: Awesome! This saved my day. I think this error was introduced on my system when I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10; applying your suggestion worked right away.

Comment: See egreg's comment on the question for the why.

Comment: @cfr, I sow it (just now), and ask him to make an answer from it.

Comment: Same solution seems to apply to all other implicitly places commands: tables, figures, itemize, multicols ... I'd worked for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let me quote the TeXbook, bottom of page 254 and top of page 255.

> The default output routine, `\shipout\box255`, illustrates one
>   extreme in which nothing is put into the vertical list that is carried over to the next page. The other extreme is
>
> ```
> \output={\unvbox255
>   \ifnum\outputpenalty<10000 \penalty\outputpenalty\fi}
> ```
>
> which ships nothing out and puts *everything* back onto the main
>   vertical list. (The command `\unvbox255` takes the completed page
>   out of its box, and the command `\penalty\outputpenalty` reinserts the
>   penalty at the chosen breakpoint.) This makes a seamless join between
>   the completed page and the subsequent material, because TeX has still
>   not discarded glue and penalties at the breakpoint when it invokes
>   an `\output` routine; hence TeX will go back and reconsider the page
>   break. If the `\vsize` hasn't changed, and if all insertions have been
>   held in place, the same page break will be found; but it will be found
>   much faster than before, because the vertical list has already been
>   constructed—the paragraphing doesn't need to be done again. Of course,
>   an output routine like this makes TeX spin its wheels endlessly, so
>   it is of no use except as an example of an extreme case.
>
> To prevent such looping, your output routine should always
>   make progress of some sort whenever it comes into play. If you make a mistake,
>   TeX may be able to help you diagnose the error, because a special
>   loop-detection mechanism has been built in:
>   There is an internal integer variable called `\deadcycles`,
>   which is cleared to zero after every `\shipout` and increased by 1
>   just before every `\output`. Thus, `\deadcycles` keeps track of how
>   many times an output routine has been initiated since the most recent
>   `\shipout`, unless you change the value of `\deadcycles` yourself.
>   There's also an integer parameter called `\maxdeadcycles`, which plain
>   TeX sets to 25. If `\deadcycles` is greater than or equal to
>   `\maxdeadcycles` when your output routine is about to be started (i.e.,
>   when `\deadcycles` is about to be increased), TeX issues an error
>   message and performs the default output routine instead of yours.

LaTeX sets `\maxdeadcycles` to 100.

With a normal document consisting only of a `table` environment, nothing particular happens. However, `preview` works by throwing away everything but the chosen pieces, in this case the floats.

It does this using the standard mechanism, but now, being the default positioning of a float `tbp`, the output routine is called by `\end{document}` but ships out nothing, because nothing triggers flushing the float queues. So the `\deadcycles` mechanism enters in the scene; the float can never be positioned, but it is still there, so TeX tries again, failing in the same way.

No matter how high you set the value of `\maxdeadcycles`, the error will arrive nonetheless, maybe a bit later. At that point, the default output routine is used and the insertions are eventually shipped out.

Solutions: use `[htp]` as a positioning argument, or add some text outside the float, which will be thrown away, but will allow the float to be positioned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}

uncommented dummy text

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  *{6}{
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
      table-format=8.2
     ]
  }
}
\toprule
0  & {1} &  {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} \\
\midrule
1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(I fixed the table specifications.)

On the other hand, you get the same result much more easily with `standalone`:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  *{6}{
    S[table-number-alignment = center,
      table-format=8.2
     ]
  }
}
\toprule
0  & {1} &  {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} \\
\midrule
1 & 11802316.16 & 10270230.14 &  210947.01 & 6716332.35 & 6808728.66 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]